# toString error returning the wrong result

Tags: java

I was tasked with creating 4 java classes to start a project on a cribbage game.  I have completed 3 of them and just have a toString error with the last one.

Here is the code for my game Class

```
public class Game implements CribbageConstants {

    private Player player1, player2;
    private boolean player1Deals;
    private Game game;

    /**
     * No argument constructor - set default values for Game
     */
    public Game() {
        player1 = new Player("?");
        player2 = new Player("?");
        player1Deals = true;



    }

    // convenience constructor
    public Game(Player player1, Player player2) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
        this.player1Deals = true;

    }

    //mutator
    public void setPlayer1(Player player1) {
        this.player1 = player1;

    }

    public void setPlayer2(Player player2) {
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    public void setPlayer1Deals(boolean player1Deals) {
        this.player1Deals = player1Deals;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    //utility methods
    public Player getPlayer1() {
        return player1;
    }

    public Player getPlayer2() {
        return player2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the player1Deals
     */
    public boolean isPlayer1Deals() {
        return player1Deals;
    }

    /**
     * @return the game
     */
    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

//-----------utility methods------------

    public String toString() {
        return "Game between " + player1 + " and " + player2;
    }

}
```

Here is my testToString code

```
public void testToString() {
        System.out.println("toString");
        Game instance = new Game();
        Player p1 = new Player("Jim");
        p1.setHand(hand1);
        Player p2 = new Player("George");
        p2.setHand(hand2);
        assertEquals("Game between ? (0) and ? (0)", instance.toString());
        instance.setPlayer1(p1);
        assertEquals("Game between Jim (0) and ? (0)", instance.toString());
        instance.setPlayer2(p2);
        assertEquals("Game between Jim (0) and George (0)", instance.toString());
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Failed: expected <Game between ?([0) and ? (0)]> 
but was: Game between ? ([AC, AC, AC, AC, AC, AC) @0 and ? (AC, AC, AC, AC, AC, AC) @ 0]>
```

NOTE - AC AC AC AC AC AC was the specified default hand from a previous class.  I'm just perplexed as to why player1 and player2 are returning the default hands and not the names

Here is the code for my Player Class

```
/*
 * player class
 */
package model;

public class Player implements CribbageConstants {

    //-----fields------
    private String name;
    private Hand hand;
    private int position;

    //---------- Constructors ---------   delete constructors for 33.3%
    /**
     * No argument constructor - set default values for card
     */
    public Player() {
        name = "?";
        hand = new Hand();
        position = 0;
    }

    // convenience constructor
    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        hand = new Hand();    
    }

    //------mutator-----
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHand(Hand hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
    //-------------- Utility methods --------------

    /**
     * Provide a text representation of a hand.
     *
     * @return the hand's cards
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Hand getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

//-----------utility methods------------
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + hand + ")" + " @ " + position;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my toString for the Player Class

```
public void testToString() {
        System.out.println("toString");
        Player instance = new Player();
        assertEquals("? (AC, AC, AC, AC, AC, AC) @ 0", instance.toString());
        instance.setName("Alexander");
        instance.setHand(hand2);
        instance.setPosition(50);
        assertEquals("Alexander (7H, 8C, QS, AH, 4D, 4S) @ 50", instance.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your other classes, since the issue is probably in one of them?

Comment: you have created the two layer in the Game class constructor with default hands. So when you use instance,toString(). IT's printing the default hand because you have created them with default hands. Player p1 and p2 that you have created is different from them.They have created with names but you haven't use them for printing

Comment: There, I added the code for the player class and the toString request for it as well.  That's where the default hand is coming from

Comment: Answers to your immediate question can be found below.  However, I would urge you to consider encapsulating what `toString()` does for each class: for example, I would argue that `Player`'s `toString()` method should not invoke `Hand` or `Hand`'s `toString()` method.  I would use `player.getHand().toString()` if I wanted to print out that information.  At least write test classes/methods for each class's `toString()` individually -- it will make it easier to figure out where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need an attribute of type Game inside of the Game class.
2. You need to assign the newly created players to your game before it will be able to toString() them.

Comment: So what exactly should I do?  I'm really not sure at all.

Comment: Your first assert should be: assertEquals("Game between ? (AC, AC, AC, AC, AC, AC) @ 0 and ? (AC, AC, AC, AC, AC, AC) @ 0", instance.toString());

Comment: Your '(0)' should be the default or actual hands depending on where in the test you are up to.

Comment: I'm only allowed to change the classes. Sorry

Comment: My general advice is to look very carefully at the actual output of the assert, decide if it is working correctly, then figure out why you expected it to be something different.

Comment: Then you need to change the default hand, and not output a position if there isn't one.